# Getting FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: 'data' when that folder exists

Tags: python

So, I'm making a Python application which has a login system, and it saves the (encrypted) username and password in `data/security/logininfo.txt`. Here's my code:

```py
import os
os.chdir("data")
os.chdir("security")
info = open("logininfo.txt", "r")
```

But it keeps giving me this error (the folders `data` and `security` exist already):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Me/Desktop/Project/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    os.chdir("data")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is "data" in your current working directory or the script's directory?

Comment: Can you add `print(os.getcwd())`? You haven't told us where this "data" directory is. The one place we know that it isn't is your current working directory.

Comment: Not enough information, voting to close.

Comment: code may run in different folder then you expect and then it search `data` in this folder and it can't find it in this folder because it doesn't exist - first check `print(os.getcwd())` and `print(os.listdir())` to see where you run code. You can also find questions how to get folder with code - something like `os.path.absolute(__file__)` - and use it to create full path to folder `data`.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to open the file by changing your code to the following:

```
with open('./data/security/logninfo.txt', 'r') as c:
     info = c
```

Comment: If changing to "data" doesn't work, it means that "data" isn't in the local directory and this won't work either.

Comment: @tdelaney My first answer stated that, but the OP said it was.

Comment: OP needs to add the information to the question. We need to know where "data" is located and what the current working directory is when the script is run. Until then, its just a waiting game.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check where Python is actually looking to. First of all you can `print(os.getcwd())` and check if it corresponds to the directory you think is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Description**
Python method chdir() changes the current working directory to the given path.It returns None in all the cases.

**Syntax**
Following is the syntax for chdir() method −

```
os.chdir(path)
```

Parameters
**path − This is complete path of the directory to be changed to a new location.**

```
path = str(os.getcwd()) + "/data"
os.chdir( path )
```

Comment: Oh 'm sorry I was confused with Django, I mean your python script

Comment: Even then, OP is trying to change relative to the current working directory. We just have to wait until OP tells us about where the data directory is and what current working directory is.

Comment: I updated my answer: this is a copy past from the doc

Comment: Since OP won't give us the needed information I don't see how any answer will help!

Comment: If the data directory is in the current directory you can do it, I updated my answer again

Comment: But that's the thing. "data" clearly isn't in the current working directory or `os.chdir("data")` would have succeeded. I'm fairly certain that "data" is in the script's directory but OP is executing from somewhere else. But since OP won't tell us, there is no way we can solve the problem.